# Ambiguity regarding passing 3 dimensional array to function in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have defined a 3 dimensional array of `int`s in my program (test[2][6][6]). Please have a look at below given program. I want to pass test[0] and test[1] to display function. For sure I am passing wrong array address functions and getting invalid results. I have tabulated array values, expected results and actual results below. Can anybody help me to get expected results by passing the right array address to the display function?

---

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct test_t
{
    int i4_x;
} test_t;

void display(test_t (*pas_test)[6][6])
{
    int row_idx = 0, col_idx = 1;
    printf("\nTOP   X: %04d", pas_test[row_idx][col_idx]->i4_x);

    row_idx = 0, col_idx = 5;
    printf("\nLEFT  X: %04d", pas_test[row_idx][col_idx]->i4_x);

    row_idx = 1, col_idx = 0;
    printf("\nRIGHT X: %04d", pas_test[row_idx][col_idx]->i4_x);
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    test_t test[2][6][6];
    int table_idx = 0, row_idx = 0, col_idx = 0, i4_cnt = 0;

    for(table_idx = 0; table_idx < 2; table_idx++)
    {
        for(row_idx = 0; row_idx < 6; row_idx++)
        {
            for(col_idx = 0; col_idx < 6; col_idx++)
            {
                test[table_idx][row_idx][col_idx].i4_x = i4_cnt;
                i4_cnt++;
            }
        }
    }

    /* ARRAY */
    for(table_idx = 0; table_idx < 2; table_idx++)
    {
        for(row_idx = 0; row_idx < 6; row_idx++)
        {
            for(col_idx = 0; col_idx < 6; col_idx++)
            {
                printf("%04d\t",test[table_idx][row_idx][col_idx].i4_x);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n\nTABLE[0]"); display(&test[0]);
    printf("\n\nTABLE[1]"); display(&test[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

---

ARRAY Values:

```
TABLE[0]
0000    0001    0002    0003    0004    0005
0006    0007    0008    0009    0010    0011
0012    0013    0014    0015    0016    0017
0018    0019    0020    0021    0022    0023
0024    0025    0026    0027    0028    0029
0030    0031    0032    0033    0034    0035

TABLE[1]
0036    0037    0038    0039    0040    0041
0042    0043    0044    0045    0046    0047
0048    0049    0050    0051    0052    0053
0054    0055    0056    0057    0058    0059
0060    0061    0062    0063    0064    0065
0066    0067    0068    0069    0070    0071
```

Expected results:

```
TABLE[0]
TOP   X: 0001
LEFT  X: 0005
RIGHT X: 0006

TABLE[1]
TOP   X: 0037
LEFT  X: 0041
RIGHT X: 0042
```

Actual results:

```
TABLE[0]
TOP   X: 0006
LEFT  X: 0030
RIGHT X: 0036

TABLE[1]
TOP   X: 0042
LEFT  X: 0066
RIGHT X: 0072
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one superfluous indexation level.

You should call your `display` function like this :

```
printf("\n\nTABLE[0]"); display(test[0]); /* note no & */
printf("\n\nTABLE[1]"); display(test[1]);
```

and declare it consistently :

```
void display(test_t pas_test[6][6]) /* note no * */
{
    int row_idx = 0, col_idx = 1;
    printf("\nTOP   X: %04d", pas_test[row_idx][col_idx].i4_x); /* note . instead of -> */

    row_idx = 0, col_idx = 5;
    printf("\nLEFT  X: %04d", pas_test[row_idx][col_idx].i4_x);

    row_idx = 1, col_idx = 0;
    printf("\nRIGHT X: %04d", pas_test[row_idx][col_idx].i4_x);
    printf("\n");
}
```

That way, you pass the bi-dimensionnal arrays contained in your 3-dimensional global array.

And output is as expected :

```
TABLE[0]
TOP   X: 0001
LEFT  X: 0005
RIGHT X: 0006


TABLE[1]
TOP   X: 0037
LEFT  X: 0041
RIGHT X: 0042
```

Comment: This is a valid alternative and simpler way to write the display code

Comment: I like this approach. It is very simple and easily understandable.

Answer (score 3):

The parameter `test` of the function `display` is a pointer to a 2 dimensional array of `test_t` structs.

You correctly pass that type:

```
printf("\n\nTABLE[0]"); display(&test[0]);
printf("\n\nTABLE[1]"); display(&test[1]);
```

But then you incorrectly calculate the offsets. Instead of first calculating the outer most dimension( lets call it the first dimension ) and then inner ones( call them second and third ) like this:

```
      first-v     v-third
test_t test[2][6][6];
               ^-second

printf("\nTOP X: %04d", (*pas_test)[row_idx][col_idx].i4_x);
```

or

```
printf("\nTOP X: %04d", pas_test[0][row_idx][col_idx].i4_x);
```

You first calculate the first and the second dimension using the variables `row_idx` and `col_idx` which are indented for the second and third dimension respectively.

```
printf("\nTOP   X: %04d", pas_test[row_idx][col_idx]->i4_x);
```

this is identical to

```
printf("\nTOP   X: %04d", (*( pas_test[row_idx][col_idx])).i4_x);
```

As you can see `row_idx` is used to calculate the first dimension instead of being used to calculate the second dimension.

Change your display function accordingly:

```
void display(test_t (*pas_test)[6][6])
{
    int row_idx = 0, col_idx = 1;
    printf("\nTOP X: %04d", pas_test[0][row_idx][col_idx].i4_x);

    row_idx = 0, col_idx = 5;
    printf("\nLEFT X: %04d", pas_test[0][row_idx][col_idx].i4_x);

    row_idx = 1, col_idx = 0;
    printf("\nRIGHT X: %04d", pas_test[0][row_idx][col_idx].i4_x);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Or alternatively in the form:

```
    int row_idx = 0, col_idx = 1;
    printf("\nTOP X: %04d", (*pas_test)[row_idx][col_idx].i4_x );
```

https://ideone.com/UHNOWV

Comment: One way of looking at this is that the parameter type is `test_t (*array)[6][6]`, so in the code, `(*array)` is the array pointed at, and `(*array)[n][m]` accesses the `[n][m]` element of that array.

Comment: Thank you guys for quick response. Let me try these suggestions. Good day.

Comment: Thank you @2501 for precise explanation.